# Eliminar o modificar un elemento xml con xslt

Tags: xml, xpath, xslt

Trabajo con documentos xml con un etiquetado de muy alta granularidad (etiquetamos a menudo a nivel de letra). En ocasiones, se hace necesario modificar un elemento xml o eliminarlo, pero conservando todo su contenido (que pasa a ser contenido de su ancestro). Por ejemplo, tengo ciertas letras etiquetadas individualmente dentro de ciertas palabras y quiero eliminar la etiqueta, pero conservar la letra.

Un ejemplo sencillo sería este:

```
        <lg>
           <l n="1267"><pc ana="editorial">›</pc><w><choice><orig><hi rendition="hc:RedStroke">N</hi>u</orig><reg><hi rendition="hc:RedStroke">n</hi>u</reg></choice></w><w>ſait</w><w join="right">mir</w><w join="left">z</w><w>her</w><w>durch</w><w>di</w><lb n="2"/><w>want</w><pc>·</pc><pc ana="editorial">.‹</pc></l>
           <l n="1268"><pc ana="editorial">›</pc><w><choice><orig><hi rendition="hc:RedStroke">M</hi>aister</orig><reg><hi rendition="hc:RedStroke">m</hi>aister</reg></choice></w><pc ana="editorial">,</pc><w>ez</w><w>iſt</w><w>niht</w><w>ſo</w><w>gewant</w><pc>·</pc><pc ana="editorial">.‹</pc></l>
        </lg>
```

Quiero eliminar la etiqueta `<hi>` que se encuentra dentro de la etiqueta `<reg>` y conservar intacto su contenido. Con xpath puedo localizar todas esas etiquetas (`//reg/hi`) y eliminarlas luego manualmente. Pero me figuro que tiene que haber una forma más sencilla, probablemente con xslt, para eliminarlas todas. O para modificarlas si ese fuera el caso. ¿Alguien sabe?

Answer (score 0):

XSLT es una herramienta ideal para esas tareas, simplemente utilizas la transformación recursiva de identidad como base del programa XSLT y entonces añades reglas con `xsl:template` para los elementos que quieres transformar:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:template match="reg/hi">
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jxDiMC7

En este caso, la regla para `reg/hi` elementos simplemente procesa el contenido del elemento `hi`. Como la declaración `<xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>` copia cada nivel recursivamente, se copia todo el documento salvo los elementos `hi` que son hijos de elementos `reg`.

Para elimnar un elemento y su contenido completamente, se usa una regla vacía: `<xsl:template match="reg/hi"/>`.

El ejemplo utiliza la version actual de XSLT, que es 3.0 de 2017. Se puede utilizar con Saxon 9.8 o 9.9 o Saxon 10 de http://saxon.sourceforge.net/ o con Altova 2017 o más actual.

Pero en versiones más antiguas de XSLT, como XSLT 1 or 2, se puede expresar el ejemplo casi tan sencillo:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="reg/hi">
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jxDiMC7/1

XSLT 1 es la versión más antigua (de 1999), sin embargo, si quieres aplicar XSLT directamente en un navegador como Chrome, Firefox, Edge or Internet Explorer, es la única versión que puedes utilizar.